# Slow canvas performance using clip region

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating some smoke using a particle emitter in Canvas. Everything is working fine but the design requires I add a mask to the canvas so we can see the page background. When I add a clipping region, I get extremely poor performance especially in Safari. Is there anything I can to do to optimise the performance when using a clip region?

Here's the smoke with no mask

http://codepen.io/fatlinesofcode/pen/AcLim

and with the mask

http://codepen.io/fatlinesofcode/pen/GLFqf

I'm drawing a vector region each time within the render loop.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(960, 00);
ctx.lineTo(960, 500);
ctx.lineTo(960 / 2, 550);
ctx.lineTo(0, 500);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, context.clip is expensive.

Perhaps use an overlay mask instead of a clipping mask.

Since you're just blitting the overlay mask onto the canvas it's much faster than calculating which pixels are in the clipping path.

**Step#1: draw your smoke**

[image]!

**Step#2: draw the overlay mask which hides the unwanted part of the smoke**

Left: the overlay mask.
Right: the smoke with the overlay mask.

[image][image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/uHg4E/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var maskCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var maskCtx=maskCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/mountain.png";
    function start(){

        makeOverlayMask();

        var smokeImage = new Image();
        smokeImage.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
        smokeImage.onload = function () {

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            for(var y=0;y<canvas.height;y+=smokeImage.height){
                ctx.drawImage(smokeImage,canvas.width/2-15,y);
            }
            ctx.drawImage(maskCanvas,0,0);

        }
    }

    function makeOverlayMask(){
        maskCanvas.width=img.width;
        maskCanvas.height=img.height+166;
        //
        maskCtx.drawImage(img,0,166);
        //
        maskCtx.save();
        maskCtx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";    
        maskCtx.beginPath();
        maskCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
        maskCtx.lineTo(320, 00);
        maskCtx.lineTo(320, 166);
        maskCtx.lineTo(320 / 2, 183);
        maskCtx.lineTo(0, 166);
        maskCtx.closePath();
        maskCtx.fill();
        maskCtx.restore();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 also just a heads up if you didn't know imgur supports CORS heh its so much better being able to upload and then use an image from imgur now then work with dataURL's for demos/answer fiddles.

Comment: @Loktar Thanks. :-) Yep, imgur is great for delivering CORS compliant images.  I use dropbox.com myself to deliver CORS compliant images.  I left the "smoke" dataURL from the questioners code in the demo--no particular reason except for laziness(!).

Comment: Thanks, the overlay mask is mucher faster, here's my updated pen. http://codepen.io/fatlinesofcode/pen/GLFqf